# Saving an image for print on Vistaprint

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, print-production

I am making a 6x4 postcard and I want to upload it to vistaprint to print. What should one save the image in Photoshop as and what settings? Are there anything to take into consideration while designing the graphic? thanks!

Comment: You should check out their help page - the information you seek is there. The link to the help section is at the bottom of the home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a quick look at Vistaprint's website and it looks like they'll take just about any file type you can throw at them.

That being said, I usually send files for print as PDFs.

In your export settings, you would usually select printer marks (crops, bleeds, etc.). However, Vistaprint already has a bleed outline when you upload your design so just make sure you account for their standard bleed when you make your design.

You also want to export with **at least** 300dpi. That's pretty standard for print resolution.

If you want more information about printing guidelines, check out these links:

[Get Print-Ready Files from Adobe CC Applications](http://www.kopytek.com/create-print-ready-files/)

[Photoshop Print Basics](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/printing-photoshop1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Note that your results will depend on their press resolution as well as your art resolution. If you send a 600 DPI image and their prepress output is only 300 DPI, you will get a screened image that has more visible dots than you might expect. I found this problem when reproducing screened or colored text. It's not at all the same as spot colors.